# No suspend with Virtualbox 4.1.0

Tags: 11.04, virtualbox

Since I upgraded to VirtualBox 4.1.0 on my 11.04 I'm having a problem of suspending. This is a [known bug](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9260) and some suggested a workaround by adding the vboxdrv to the modules under /etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules. This indeed solved the problem but only when a VM image is not running.

Any clue how to workaround it until Oracle fixes the bug?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Problem got solved in a future release of Virtualbox.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug.  Head on over to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/814323 and say it affects you too!

thanks

Comment: ... the OP asked for a workaround... what is it?